# Is a jps process a JVM process?

Tags: java

On Ubuntu, `man jps` says

> jps - Lists the instrumented Java Virtual Machines (JVMs) on the target system.

What does a "instrumented Java Virtual Machine" mean?

```
$ jps -v
29584 Jps -Dapplication.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64 -Xms8m -Djdk.module.main=jdk.jcmd
```

Is a jps process a JVM process, by definition?

jps is an ELF file, not a JVM bytecode program compiled from a Java program:

```
$ file /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/jps
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/jps: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/l, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=3f48c70ab711b493ee793c92c19b3a884896bb4d, stripped
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you google "instrumented jvm" at all?  This question doesn't show any evidence you've even tried to do any research

Comment: What shall I say? The only one I found doesn't even define what is an instrumented JVM http://agassiz.cs.umn.edu/SanFrancisco/jvm_intro.html

Comment: @StephenHarris - I concur with Tim.  I have been trying to figure this out for the past hour via Google, looking at the source code, etc.  The answer is NOT readily available via Google.

Comment: Maybe I had more exposure to AppDev teams, so I have the necessary background.  But, anyway, this is a Java question and better on StackOverflow.  It's not a Unix question.

Comment: A sensible title would have been something like _What does "instrumented" mean in "instrumented JVM"?_  The current title reads as only asking about the process(es) running the `jps` program.  Hence no explanation of "instrumented" in the answers so far.

Comment: @StephenHarris Then please explain what difference there is between an instrumented and a non-instrumented JVM. Or is "instrumented" a kind of title, like "right honourable"?

Comment: @mosvy That definitely belongs on StackOverflow!  But in general terms an instrumented application is one that has "probes" in it to report on health/performance type stats, to allow execution tracing, etc etc  Think of an "instrumentation dashboard".   Two common commercial tools used by AppDev teams may be AppDynamics or Dynatrace.  Even the kernel can be instrumented (eg with SystemTap).   An instrumented JVM is, therefore, one where you can get stats from the JVM itself.

Comment: @StephenHarris Thanks. Apology that it perhaps does not belong here. When I run `java` command to run a compiled java program, is the created `java` process  an instrumental JVM? Is there some example of a JVM process which is not instrumented?

Comment: @StephenHarris No. `jps` starts as a separate process and then a) determines which JVMs are running b) determines whether they're instrumented or not (not sure about this part ;-)) and c) is instrumenting some data out of them. How a), b) and c) happen on a Unix system should be perfectly topical here, no matter what reflection/instrumenting/debugging interfaces java offers at language level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What does a "instrumented Java Virtual Machine" mean?

On Linux, an "instrumented Java Virtual Machine" is the vm started with the `-XX:+UsePerfData` option -- which is on by default.

That will cause it the store performance & other info into a `/tmp/hsperfdata_$USER/$PID` file, which will be read by the `jps(1)` tool.

If you want to start an un-instrumented JVM, run it as `java -XX:-UsePerfData YourClass`. That will prevent it from writing that hsperfdata and from appearing in `jps`'s output.

> Is a jps process a JVM process, by definition?

Yes

> jps is an ELF file, not a JVM bytecode program compiled from a Java program:

`jps` is just a [launcher](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/bin/main.c#l92), which will start a JVM and load the [`sun.tools.jps.Jps`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/sun/tools/jps/Jps.java) java class from `tools.jar` into it. The JVM started this way will write its own hsperfdata file, and that's why the `Jps` class appears in its own output. You can turn that off by passing the same option as above to the JVM via the [`-J`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/bin/java.c#l1285) switch:

```
$ jps
12583 Jps
$ jps -J-XX:-UsePerfData
$
```

Comment: Thanks. `jstack`, `jinfo`, `jmap` use dynamic active mechanism instead of files, to communicate with existing JVM processes. Do they require the JVM process to be instrumented? Are they themselves JVM processes and if yes, instrumented JVM processes?

Comment: Why don't you try it? start a java program with `java -XX:-UsePerfData ClassName`, get its pid with `pgrep`, and you'll see that `jstack`, `jinfo`, `jmap`  will work with it. All those programs are launchers just like `jps`, and they all accept the `-J` option to pass arguments to the JVMs they start.

Comment: For the record, the "dynamic active mechanism" seem to be `ptrace(2)` for `jinfo` and `jmap` and a `/tmp/.java_pid$PID` unix domain socket that a JVM will create upon having an `.attach_pid$PID` file created in its cwd and receiving a `SIGQUIT` signal -- for `jstack`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `jps` is a Java application.

From [an Oracle blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/corejavatechtips/the-attach-api):

> That's where the
>
> ```
> jps
> ```
>
> command comes in handy. It will list the process 
>   ids for all virtual machines started for the JDK installation directory
>   you are using. Your output, specifically the process ids, will
>   probably be different:
>
> ```
> > jps
> 5156 Jps
> 4276 MyFrame
> ```
>
> Since the
>
> ```
> jps
> ```
>
> command is itself a Java program, it shows up in the
>   list, too.

Comment: Thanks. "`jps` command is itself a Java program". But `jps `is an ELF file just like the `java` executable file, not a JVM bytecode program compiled from a Java program.  See my update

Comment: @Tim Java programs may be compiled into binary executables. See e.g. [How can I convert my Java program to an .exe file?](//stackoverflow.com/q/147181)